# GPU processing in Julia through WSL?

Tags: julia, gpu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to know whether it is possible to execute the GPU processing using WSL (Windows Subsystems Linux)? As most of the GPU packages (oneAPI, CUDA, AMD) officially only supports linux.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about Julia integration, but you would at least need the Windows Insider Preview which supports CUDA in WSL.  See https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, 
I tried accessing CUDA through WSL and manages the system to recognize NVIDIA card for computation. Now, I will try to see whether Julia is able to take advantage of CUDA through WSL.

Comment: CUDA.jl works for me on WSL2. I had to go onto the windows insider dev ring, update windows, install the nvidia driver on windows, and add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/wsl/lib"` to my `.bashrc` file in WSL so CUDA.jl could find `libcuda.so`.